# Error Correction: The board of directors want all possible facilities and allowances for itself

Tags: compound-nouns

> The board of directors want all possible facilities  and allowances for itself.

Which is the correct way to correct the above sentence ? Should I replace *itself* with *themselves* or replace *want* with *wants* ? I understand that in sentence like these I need to use singular verb/pronoun if the meaning conveyed is singular like *The Jury gave its verdict.* while I need to use plural verb/pronoun when meaning conveyed is plural e.g. *The jury are divided in their opinion.* but in the above sentence I'm not able to decide which is the correct correction.

Comment: I would say "want" is the obvious error and should be changed to "wants."

Comment: It should be "wants" if you want to align it with the word "itself". It can only be "want" if you turn the reflexive pronoun into "themselves"; otherwise, it's called "synesis" in English: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/synesis

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what "all facilities and allowances" means, but it's not really important.

"Board of Directors" is one of those tricky *collective nouns* that, if acting together, is singular, but if acting as a group of *individuals* is plural.  Either way the conjugation of the verb and the reflexive pronoun need to match.

> The Board **acts** to accrue more power to **itself**.
>
> The Board **act** to accrue more power to **themselves**.

That being said, BrE has more range with collective nouns than does AmE.  For example, in BrE "the crowd" is often plural, while in AmE it is often singular.  The British may be more comfortable with "The Board *are*", while Americans will almost always say "The Board *is*".

[More on collective nouns](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/)

Comment: It might be easist just say "The directors want... for themselves."

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if it's OK to write ***board of directors want*** in American Englsh. I would consider it a grammar error.

Comment: @Ringo I thought so too, until I came across numerous American newspaper quotes that included things like "The police **are ...**" which made me rethink how Americans deal with collective nouns.  I think we're OK with plural collectives, but we draw the line in a different place from the British.

Comment: @Ringo but in any case I edited to include your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew "Board" is a collective noun, and "board of directors" is pretty much a set phrase. Do they / should they function the same as far as singular / plural? I don't know the answer. Pretty much every collective noun I've looked at sounds weird with a plural verb, except for "police."